# Trouble spacing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am new to Java, what I am trying to do is generate a GUI with a bunch of images I have managed to generate a bunch of images, however, they have unnecessary space between them horizontally, is there any way that I can get rid of this currently I am generating them like so?

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
int numberOfTabs = 4;// number of times image is shown
for(int i = 0; i<numberOfTabs;i++) {
    add(
        new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Path to image"))));
    //creates a new image anonymous object and adds it to the jframe        
}   
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Sheetssss");
pack();
setVisible(true);
//also in this context this = a Jframe object so all these methods can be called without an object reference
```

is there some other method that I can call so that the horizontal spacing can be set to 0?
As shown in the image below there is space between the images, the 2 vertical black lines between images should be overlapping
[image]
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “ unneccessary space between them horizontally”? Can you provide and image of what you’re getting compared to what you’d like/expect

Comment: its now updated with an image

Comment: Have a look at the [FlowLayout​(int align, int hgap, int vgap)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int)) constructor

Comment: Although I might consider using a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) instead

Comment: it worked thanks I just needed to to change setLayout(new FlowLayout()) to setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout())
```

to

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,0));
```